# How to calculate the intersection point of a vector and a plane defined as a point and normal vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've read through some of the questions on line-plane intersection but I'm struggling because many define the plane in a format like:

$4x-2y+5z-9=0$,

but my plane is defined as a point ($x_p, y_p, z_p$) and the unit vector *normal* to the plane ($i_p, j_p, k_p$).

My line is defined by a point ($x_v, y_v, z_v$) and a unit vector in the direction of the line ($i_v, j_v, k_v$),

I can't figure out how to apply what I've read in other questions to my scenario, which I will need to implement in some generic VB.NET code.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It might be easier to explain with a numerical example, but basically the equation of your plane is $i_px+j_py+k_px-(i_px_p+j_py_p+k_pz_p)=0$; on the other hand, the normal vector to the plane $4x-2y+5z-9=0$ is $(4,-2,5)$

Comment: You’re only one simple step away from an equation of that form for the plane. Look up “point-normal form.”

Comment: @amd only simple if you know. Fortunately AugSB’s answer got me there.

Comment: You could’ve gotten there yourself. I’d bet that he started with that form, substituted a generic point on the line into it and then solved for the unknown multiple of the line’s unit direction vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $P_p=(x_p,y_p,z_p)$, $P_v=(x_v,y_v,z_v)$, $\vec{v_v}=(i_v,j_v,k_v)$ and $\vec{v_p}=(i_p,j_p,k_p)$. Then

$$P_{intersection} = P_v + \frac{(P_p-P_v)\cdot\vec{v_p}}{\vec{v_v}\cdot\vec{v_p}} \ \vec{v_v}$$

I assume you already know the basics of operations with vectors and points...

---

EDIT: This *formula* can be easily derived from the vectorial definition of planes and lines. A point $P$ belongs to the plane defined by $P_p$ and $\vec{v_p}$ if $(P-P_p)\cdot\vec{v_p}=0$. Moreover, points of the line defined by $P_v$ and $\vec{v_v}$ are of the form $P_v+\lambda \vec{v_v}$. Note that the intersection point has to satisfy both conditions, so it is enouh to plug in the line form into the plane equation and solve:
$$(P_v+\lambda \vec{v_v}-P_p)\cdot\vec{v_p}=0 \iff \lambda =\frac{(P_p-P_v)\cdot\vec{v_p}}{\vec{v_v}\cdot\vec{v_p}}$$
Of course, if $\vec{v_v}\cdot\vec{v_p}=0$, both elements would be parallel, so there would not be any intersection point.

---

Edit: the originally stated formula was incorrect. This has now been fixed.

Comment: Its been a while but yes! Use dot product on the vectors right? I best get refreshing...

Comment: This answer would be much improved if you explained how you arrived at this mysterious formula.

Comment: @amd mysterious answer that works great.

Comment: @amd It is not so misterious, you can find it in plenty of webpages (starting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93plane_intersection) itself). Anyhow, I added a brief explanation to complete the answer.

Comment: It is mysterious when you present it as a fact accompli with no explanation or references.

Comment: @amd The final objective of the OP is to implement the formula in VB.NET. The way to deduce it is not the point of the question (and I guess that the proof is even more mysterious for the OP). Moreover, it remains to transform math language to programming language, so the OP still has to make an effort to achieve the aim. In the end, this is what MSE is for, right?

Answer (score 0):

If $\vec P=(x,y,z)$ is some point of the plane that is given by point $\vec A$ and a normal $\vec n$, then by definition of normal the vector $\vec{AP}=\vec P -\vec A$ is perpendicular to $\vec n$, so the scalar product $\vec{AP}\cdot\vec n=0$.

By writing this in coordinate form, you will get the plane equation:
$$
(x-x_v)i_v+(y-y_v)j_v+(z-z_v)k_v = 0,\\
i_vx+j_vy+k_vz-(i_vx_v+j_vy_v+k_vz_v)=0
$$